# .htaccess send requests to a subfolder's index.php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I have searched StackOverflow for my answer, but nothing that I have seen seems to work.

I have a framework that sends all requests to an `index.php` file. Everything works when I install it in the root of the virtual host:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/home
http://example.com/home/index
```

The problem happens when I try to install the framework in a subdirectory like:

```
http://example.com/blog/
```

Requests like:

```
http://example.com/blog/home
http://example.com/blog/home/index
```

All of those requests should be sent to the index.php file that lives in /blog

My current set up is:

`http://example.com/index.php` - This file just prints out "we are in the root of the virtual host". The framework is not installed there.

`http://example.com/blog` - This works fine

When I try to get to `http://example.com/blog/home` I get the root `index.php` file, not the frameworks. I get the message "we are in the root of the virtual host".

I have the following `.htaccess` file located at `http://example.com/blog/.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine on

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that fixed my problem is:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

It appears that the Multiviews was throwing it off.

Comment: It was the fact you were mixing arguments with and without a `-` (or `+`) prefix in The `Options` directive that would have likely caused a problem. As [stated in the Apache 2.2 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options): "Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax and is **likely to cause unexpected results**.". Alternatively, you could have written `Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` - but this is then adding to (or removing) what has already been set in the server config, rather than overriding it.

Comment: And don't forget the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive, should you add any more directives.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Means "if not js or ico..." forward to `index.php`.

So, in essence, your `/blog` level `.htaccess` is saying if it's not an image or CSS file redirect it to `/blog/index.php`.

Comment: This is what I want.  I want all requests, excepted those piped, to go to the index.php page.  If I go to http://domain/blog/ this works.  When I go to http://domain/blog/home/ it goes to the http://domain/ this is the problem.

Comment: This is simply an optimisation. The first `RewriteCond` directive will otherwise exclude all requests that map to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /blog
```

Try it without the forward slash.

Comment: The trailing slash on the URL-path argument to the `RewriteBase` directive is entirely optional. In fact, the [example given for the `RewriteBase` directive in the Apache 2.2 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) includes the trailing slash, but many other examples (even on the same page) omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the requests that you're testing with for items that don't actually exist in the directory?  These lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Mean that any requests for a file or directory that exists won't be rewritten.

Comment: The directory does not exist, but could.